# Is there something unique you can get out of a set of numbers?

Tags: python

I am currently trying to solve a problem with constraint programming. My problem is that for example you need a set of numbers and you can only have a maximum number of **9** with a required length of **6** so you can get something like `[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]` now when you sum up all these numbers you will get **27** but from the given variables above you can also get `sum([1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9])` and still get **27**. But I am trying to get the exact `[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]` so my current solution for this is to get a unique "trait" from the set of numbers I have, I've tried many solutions but all of them only works on small numbers for example :

I have this array called "shifts" this is equals to [`1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]` so I am going to multiply this with the set of numbers I have based on index for example

```
1 * 1 = 1
3 * 2 = 6
4 * 3 = 12
5 * 4 = 20
6 * 5 = 30
8 * 6 = 48
-----------
= 117
```

This is different from

```
1 * 1 = 1
2 * 2 = 4
3 * 3 = 9
5 * 4 = 20
7 * 5 = 35
9 * 6 = 54
----------
= 123
```

So now from my current constraint algorithm I can look for the number **117** to get the pattern I want. The problem is the chances of duplication rises the larger the numbers in your set of numbers and the larger your required length is so when I ran my algorithm it gives me another set of numbers that fits in the constraints I have given.

So are there any unique "traits" to get from the pattern that we are looking for? So far as stated from all the things I've tried I can only get the pattern I want if the set of numbers, and required length is small enough.

*Note: Since I am using constraint programming I can't use division only floored division and no floats only integers*

Comment: The unique-ifying constraint you've described is only possible because you already know the answer. For something more general you need either to find a general property of the patterns you're looking for or to enumerate many solutions until you find the one you need.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE.  Please take the [site tour](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/tour).  What you ask about seems quite similar to a pure math problem such as this older post on Math.SE, [Minimal way to choose set $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ such that $\sum_{i =1}^n x_i$ is not other sums of $n$ numbers in $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281346/minimal-way-to-choose-set-x-x-1-x-n-such-that-sum-i-1n-x-i-is-no).  The exact requirement imposed by "using constraint programming" is unclear to me and would bear further explanation.

Comment: Are the six numbers required to be unique, or can they be repeated?  Does the order in which the numbers appear matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One simple way to do this is with a product of powers of primes.  Let the hash function be

$f(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n})=2^{x_{1}}3^{x_{2}}\cdot p_{n}^{x_{n}}$

where $p_{n}$ is the $n$th prime number.  You can easily invert the function value to extract $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$, $\ldots$, $x_{n}$.  It's well known that the prime factorization is unique, so there will be a unique solution to the inversion.  Note that if $n$ is large or any of the $x_{i}$ are large then the product might be too large to represent in a 32-bit integer.

It's likely in practice to be simpler and faster to just store a vector of numbers.

See also the related concept of a "perfect hash function."

Comment: Though I'm not crazy about making/overflowing huge primes, I do think this answer has the right idea of directing the questioner towards hash functions, which share a lot of these ideas/requirements.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done optimally, mapping bijectively each combination of $k$ numbers among $n$ into a distinct integer in $\{1,...,N\}$, with $N = \binom{n}{k}$ is as small as possible. This problem is known as *ranking* and *unranking* *combinations* (of $k=6$ numbers in $\{1,2,..,n=9\}$, in your example). It is a classical combinatorics problem described, for instance, in Knuth's *The art of computer programming*. There exist algorithms to do that, for instance see https://stackoverflow.com/q/3143142 .

Comment: It's unclear from the original question whether the 6 numbers need to be distinct or whether there could be repeated values.  If the numbers have to be distinct then ranking/unranking would be a good approach.

Comment: @BrianBorchers There is a bijection between combinations with repetitions and without: if $(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k)$ is a combination with repetitions of $1,2,\dots,n$, then $(a_1, a_2+1, \dots a_k + (k-1))$ is a combination without repetitions of $1,2,\dots,n+k-1$.